# Python.scipy: Curve_fit a function with several inputs and ouputs

Tags: python, optimization, parameters, scipy

I want to fit a function with two parameters (Km, kcat) and 4 Inputs and Outputs to some data. 
The function is:

```
def dxdt(x, t, Km, kcat):
    y = np.zeros(4)
    reaction1 = Km * x[2] * x[0]
    reaction2 = kcat * x[3]
    y[0] = - reaction1
    y[1] = reaction2
    y[2] = reaction2 - reaction1
    y[3] = reaction1 - reaction2
return y
```

for example, the data could be:

```
x = [[7.2, 6.1, 5.5, 4.1, 3.3, 2.1, 1.9, 0.2], [0., 1.1, 2.2, 3.5, 
4.5, 6.0, 6.6, 7.3], [10., 9.5, 8., 7.1, 6.8, 5., 5.9, 9.9], [0., 1.2, 
3., 4.5, 5., 6.1, 2.5, 0.4 ]]
```

with timespan:

```
t = range(9)
```

and fixed starting values:

```
initial_values = [7.2., 0., 10., 0.]
```

I define a function which calculates the output for a given set of parameters:

```
def y(timerange, a, b):    
    result = odeint(dxdt, initial_values, timerange, 
                    args=(a, b))
return result.transpose()
```

Now, I do not know how to use scipy.optimize.curvefit() properly.
I have only seen curve_fit examples with functions going from R^n -> R but not from R^n->R^n.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use `leastsq`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from scipy.integrate import odeint
def dxdt(x, t, Km, kcat):
    y = np.zeros(4)
    reaction1 = Km * x[2] * x[0]
    reaction2 = kcat * x[3]
    y[0] = - reaction1
    y[1] = reaction2
    y[2] = reaction2 - reaction1
    y[3] = reaction1 - reaction2
    return y
x = np.array([[7.2, 6.1, 5.5, 4.1, 3.3, 2.1, 1.9, 0.2], [0., 1.1, 2.2, 3.5, 4.5, 6.0, 6.6, 7.3], [10., 9.5, 8., 7.1, 6.8, 5., 5.9, 9.9], [0., 1.2, 3., 4.5, 5., 6.1, 2.5, 0.4 ]])
t = range(8)
initial_values = [7.2, 0., 10., 0.]
def y(timerange, a, b):    
    result = odeint(dxdt, initial_values, timerange, 
                args=(a, b))
    return result.transpose()
def residuals(params):
    a,b=params
    return (y(t,a,b)-x).flatten()
result=leastsq(residuals,[0.1,0.1])
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you! That works for me. What does the second output mean? (The one) 
Output:
array([ 0.04744236,  0.33046273]), 1

Comment: According to documentation: «An integer flag. If it is equal to 1, 2, 3 or 4, the solution was found. Otherwise, the solution was not found. In either case, the optional output variable ‘mesg’ gives more information.»